# How do I set the finder view to only list files and folder by name and not group by date modified?

Tags: finder, mojave

I'm using Mojave.

I like to have all folders displayed in list view and sorted by name.

I set the finder view options to sort by name, unchecked "Use relative dates" and clicked "Use as Defaults".

But if I go to upload a file, the finder groups files and folders by date modifed (today, yesterday, May, April...).

Is there an easy way to change this so that I can only see it listed by name when I go to upload?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at the top left of a Finder window, on the Toolbar, there are four icons for sorting files, and by default has the word View under them.

The second icon will show files in list view, and you can then click on the Name column to sort the files by name, as seen in the image below.

[image]